# Materialize: icons with text in a list

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using [**Materialize**](http://materializecss.com/) to structure a webpage.

I want to put a menu where each element have an icon with related text:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="center-align row">
          <li class="waves-effect col s3">
              <i class="material-icons">home</i> <!-- Icon-->
              HOME                               <!-- Text-->
          </li>

          <li class="waves-effect col s3">
              <i class="material-icons">face</i>
              ABOUT
          </li>
          <li class="waves-effect col s3">
              <i class="material-icons">collections</i>
              GALLERIES
          </li>
          <li class="waves-effect col s3">
              <i class="material-icons">email</i>
              CONTACT
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

The problem is that only the icon is rendered and not the text:

[image: Nav menu]

I imagine that this is for a CSS property in the `<li>` element in Materialize. What do I need to do if I want to show the text as well?

Comment: Is the `<li>` text-color maybe black?

Comment: A CSS `font-size: 0` declaration may be affecting your navigation bar, it's commonly used to eliminate unexpected white space around navigation list elements. Setting a `font-size` to the `<li>` could potentially fix this.

Comment: surely css code is doing something important. Provide css too.

Comment: can you post a fiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I added `display: inline` in `nav ul .waves-effect i` and the problem was solved!

```
 nav ul .waves-effect i {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `<span>` tag like this :

```
<li class="waves-effect col s3">
    <i class="material-icons">home</i> <!-- Icon-->
    <span>Home</span>                  <!-- Text-->
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are not able to see the Text. As I have just copied pasted your code and I can see Text along with icons.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<nav>
    <ul class="center-align row">
          <li class="waves-effect col s3">
              <i class="material-icons">home</i> <!-- Icon-->
              HOME                               <!-- Text-->
          </li>

          <li class="waves-effect col s3">
              <i class="material-icons">face</i>
              ABOUT
          </li>
          <li class="waves-effect col s3">
              <i class="material-icons">collections</i>
              GALLERIES
          </li>
          <li class="waves-effect col s3">
              <i class="material-icons">email</i>
              CONTACT
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```